# Producing a line on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to post a legend on ggplot for my `geom_vline`.
 I am plotting a data set (see below) and graphing to vlines (one is the mean and one is the user data).

Here is the data:

```
orig_quant
  std_curve_rsq    slope cluster_density
1     0.9989831 1.036102          240000
2     0.9991298 1.022148          240000
3     0.9996155 1.036922          240000
4     0.9989831 1.036102          240000
5     0.9989831 1.036102          240000

flowcell_batch_value
  std_curve_rsq     slope cluster_density
1        0.9799 0.9623146          240000
```

Here is my script:

```
std_plot = ggplot(data = orig_quant, aes(orig_quant$std_curve_rsq)) +
    geom_histogram(breaks = seq(min(orig_quant$std_curve_rsq) -sd(orig_quant$std_curve_rsq),
        max(orig_quant$std_curve_rsq)+sd(orig_quant$std_curve_rsq), by =
        sd(orig_quant$std_curve_rsq)),
        col="red", fill="green", alpha = .2) +
    labs(title = "Quantitation Std_Curve_Rsq") +
    labs(x = "std_curve_rsq", y = "Frequency") +
#need mean value in legend

#need user value in legend as well
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = flowcell_batch_value, na.rm=T), color = "blue",
        linetype = "solid", size=2, show.legend = TRUE)
```

[image: geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(std_curve_rsq,na.rm=T)),color="red", linetype="solid", size=2, show.value = TRUE)]

For reference, `orig_quant` is a set of data and `std_curve_rsq` is the column of data. What I am also doing is drawing a line at the mean of the data set, and a line at where the users data is (`flowcell_batch_value_std_curve`).

What I want is to is have a legend that states the values of both those lines. The mean and the user value. I tried doing that by using examples from [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/) but it hasn't been working...do you know why it it hasn't been working?

I added one of the graphs I currently get. As you can see, I generate the bargraph (good) and the two lines, one for the mean (red) and user data (blue). Ideally I would like a legend stating the two lines and the values for those lines. But for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: With ggplot2 you cannot really add everything you want in the legend but just the variable mapped to an aesthetic (colour, shape,size..). I suggest you to use annotation for your purpose

Comment: Cannot reproduce your plot. But as adiana already said, something like this would work `std_plot + annotate("text",x = std_curve_rsq[1] ,y = 2,label=std_curve_rsq[1])`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you message me why its not reproducing for you, maybe I can help. 
Also I tried adding the line 
annotate("text",x = std_curve_rsq[1] ,y = 2,label=std_curve_rsq[1])
But it didnt seem to help. There was no change made to my plot.

Comment: Okay I got it to work. but the problem is that I I am trying to add two annotation. I need to add 2, one for the mean and one for the user data. When I add one the other one disappears. I was trying this.

std_plot + annotate("text", x = mean(orig_quant$std_curve_rsq, y = 30, label = "Some text")
std_plot + annotate("text", x = flowcell_batch_value$std_curve_rsq, y = 30, label = "Some text")
it will graph the first one, but then if I run the second command it will graph that and delete the first one.